# Find the remainder when $\sum_{n=1}^{2015}{n^2\times2^n}$is divided by 23.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, chinese-remainder-theorem

> Find the remainder when $\sum_{n=1}^{2015}{n^2\times2^n}$is divided by 23.

I am completely stuck at this to even start , here's the samll thing that I have noticed .
When $2^{11}$ is divided by 23 , the remainder is $1$ , so $2^{11k+r}$ is equivalent to $2^r$ (mod 23) , for any natural number $k$.
Apart from this nothing useful thing came to my mind .

Could someone please help me to find the remainder ?

Thanks !

Comment: $n^2$ repeats periodically modulo $23$ with period $23$, so by the Chinese remainder theorem $n^2\cdot2^n$ repeats with period $23\cdot11$. That opens up a possibility... Observe that both factors cycle their values independently from each other.

Comment: I'd rather find the [explicit sum](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+k%5E2*2%5Ek+for+k%3D1..n). $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k^2\cdot 2^k=2(2^n\cdot n^2-2^{n+1}\cdot n+3\cdot 2^n-3)$. [The answer](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/v6AoM69Eg6u4NFcjW0vLCAi1shXS8osUshUy8xSKEvPSUzWMDAzNNDVVjYy5NP//BwA) is $5$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen What's *"your trick"* to see that $n^2$ repeats periodically modulo $23$?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net $(n+23)^2\equiv n^2\pmod{23}$.

Comment: Shame on me!!!! Beauty is that it's true for $23$ as well as for every number and every power. Never realized that!

Comment: The indepent periods (and the sum of squares, or powers of two) give that with $2015$ replaces with any multiple of $253$ would have remainder $0$. Do you see why? Therefore...

Comment: Maybe there's a way to prove $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{23\cdot 11} k^2\cdot 2^k\equiv 0\pmod{23}$, then use $2015\equiv -9\pmod{23\cdot 11}$.

Comment: Just to explain one way to get @AlexeyBurdin's explicit sum: use  $$\sum_{k=1}^nx^k ={x^{n+1}-x\over x -1},$$ apply $x {d\over dx}$ twice, and set $x=2$.

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin What I was trying to get at it with my "hint" is that as a consequence of the two periods being coprime (so CRT applies)
$$\sum_{k=1}^{23\cdot11}k^2\cdot2^k\equiv\left(\sum_{j=0}^{22} j^2\right)\left(\sum_{i=0}^{10}2^i\right)\pmod{23}.$$ Each $k$ matches with a unique pair $(i,j)$ and vice versa.

Comment: Both parenthesis are $0$ ) (not sure how to prove it though) So it suffices to show $\sum\limits_{k=-8}^0 2^k\cdot k^2\equiv -5\pmod{23}$

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin $$\sum_{j=0}^nj^2=\frac16 n(n+1)(2n+1),$$ $$\sum_{i=0}^k2^i=2^{k+1}-1.$$ I'm sure the participants of the contest this is from were expected to know those :-) Actually, given that $2$ has order $11$ modulo $23$, its powers are exactly the non-zero quadratic residues, so those two sums are trivially congruent to each other modulo $23$.

Comment: Oops. The squares are included twice, so the former sum is congruent to twice the latter because it also runs over the quadratic residues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With $k=1,2,\cdots,23$ one has $n^22^n\equiv(23m+k)^22^{23m+k}\equiv k^22^{m+k}\pmod{23}$ and since $2015=87\cdot23+14$ you have
$$\sum_1^{23}n^22^n\equiv\sum_1^{23}k^22^k=A\pmod{23}\\\sum_{24}^{46}n^22^n\equiv\sum_1^{23}k^22^{k+1}=2A\pmod{23}\\..................................\\..................................\\\sum_{86*23+1}^{87*23}n^22^n\equiv\sum_1^{23}k^22^{86+k}=2^{86}A\pmod{23}$$
Then$$\sum_1^{2001}n^22^2\equiv(1+2+2^3+\cdots+2^{86})A=(2^{87}-1)A\pmod{23}$$ The actual calculation of this is not difficult modulo $23$ and so over the last $14$ terms in play.Naturally you can apply the  little known formula given by  Alexey Burdin above but here it is about making efforts not to apply that formula.

►I want to verify this way the answer given by the formula above which is $5$.

We have $$A\equiv6\pmod{23}\\2^{87}-1\equiv{11}\pmod{23}\\(2^{87}-1)A\equiv{20}\pmod{23}$$
The remaining $14$ terms partially add up the following module $23$ residus:
$$18+1+14+21=8\pmod{23}$$ therefore
$$20+8=28\equiv\color{red}5\pmod{23}$$

Indeed, the answers coincide.

Answer (score 2):

Since $2^{11}\equiv 1 \pmod{23}$ then the following holds for integers $q,r\geq 0$:

$$(q23+r)^2 \cdot 2^{q23+r} \equiv r^2 \cdot 2^{q+r} \pmod{23}$$
Therefore:
$$ \sum_{r=0}^{22} (q23+r)^2 \cdot 2^{q23+r} \equiv 2^q \sum_{r=0}^{22} r^2 \cdot 2^{r} \pmod{23}$$
$$ \sum_{q=0}^{87} \sum_{r=0}^{22} (q23+r)^2 \cdot 2^{q23+r} \equiv (\sum_{q=0}^{87} 2^q) \sum_{r=0}^{22} r^2 \cdot 2^{r} \pmod{23}$$
Since $\sum_{q=0}^{87} 2^q \equiv 0 \pmod{23}$ (why?)
we get $\sum_{n=0}^{88 \cdot 23 -1} n^2 2^n \equiv 0 \pmod{23}$. Does it help?
($88 \cdot 23 -1= 2023$ is not so far from $2015$ ... )

Comment: Yes , I was able to solve from here , in fact , I have seen many ways of solving this now , thanks !

Comment: @ARROW You are welcome :) The more ways you see, the more you can learn.

Answer (score 1):

So what you said and the fact that $n^2 \equiv(n \mod 23)^2  \pmod{23}$ and $12 \equiv -11 \pmod{23}$ and $13 \equiv -10 \pmod {23}$ and so on makes a periodic sum: (let the sum be $S$)
$$S \equiv 1^2\cdot2^1+\dots+11^2\cdot2^{11}$$
$$+(-11)^2\cdot2^{1}+(-10)^2\cdot2^2+\dots+(-1)^2\cdot2^{11}+0+\dots$$
and of course the square makes the negative go out. So we need to find out that $2015=23\cdot87+14$ which makes
$$S \equiv 87(1^2\cdot2^1+\dots+11^2\cdot2^{11}+11^2\cdot2^{1}+10^2\cdot2^2+\dots+1^2\cdot2^{11}+0)$$
$$+1^2\cdot2^1+\dots+11^2\cdot2^{11}+11^2\cdot2^{1}+10^2\cdot2^2+9^2\cdot2^3 \tag{since $14\equiv -9 \pmod{23}$}$$
and that makes the rest easy to compute.